# How to figure out proper xpath for importxml in google sheets?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to import and use XML data from 
http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_std.cgi?ico=00064581

to Google Sheets with function IMPORTXML,

trying to get a subject name, id, and address (etc.), but I cannot figure out proper xpath to get it, receiving Imported content is empty. I can do //*, but this is not exactly what i need. Could you suggest me some hints please?

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use something like this as formula of a cell:

```
=importxml("http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_std.cgi?ico=00064581", "//*[name()='are:Shoda_ICO']")
```

In case you want to get multiple elements :

```
=importxml("http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_std.cgi?ico=00064581", "//*[name()='dtt:Nazev_obce' or name()='are:Shoda_ICO']")
```

Comment: Thank you. And how can I combine more of them please?
In a meantime, I solve it by IMPORTDATA, and regular use of functions, that led to this code: =REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARES!A2:A100, "select A where A starts with '<are:Obchodni_firma>'"),"\>(.*)\<")

Comment: I have tried it like this://*[contains(local-name(), 'ICO')]|//*[contains(local-name(), 'Nazev_obce')]
Is it right way?

Comment: @Jakub For some reason 'contains' didn't work with importxml, I edited the answer